# <ask> modified string using memcpy

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain what's wrong with my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main () {
    
    char x[] = "abcdefghi123456";  // length 15
    
    cout << "original string length: " << strlen(x) << endl;
    cout << "string before modified: " << x << endl;
    
    while ((strlen(x) % 4) != 0)
    
    {
        memcpy(x+strlen(x),"n",1);
    }
        
    cout << "string length after modified: " << strlen(x) << endl;
    cout << "string after modified: " << x << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The result of the code above is:

[image]

Comment: For one thing, there is no code because it's all comments

Comment: I'd also point out that going outside the bounds of an array is undefined behaviour; you can't expect anything at that point.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes. I can explain. You are using a char[] instead of a ````std::string````. The char array has a fixed size of 15 and connot grow. If you try to append something with memcpy, you will go out of bounds. Do not use char arrays for strings in C++

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?  Whatever it is, it more than likely doesn't require you to write code this way, i.e. using `memcpy`, repeatedly calling `strlen`, etc.

Comment: This sounds like an YX problem, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: sorry my original code wasn't like that, I added some comments because the stackoverflow can't allow posting of my posts

Comment: `<cstring>` and `<string.h>` are the same thing, the first is just the same stuff wrapped in the `std::` namespace. Use `<cstring>` exclusively instead of `<string.h>` if you're developing for C++ and you need C-string utilities. This doesn't solve whatever your problem is, but I thought you'd appreciate a shotgunning of unrelated tips from people since your actual problem has already been solved.

Comment: @Pegasus `while ((strlen(x) % 4) != 0)` -- If you're going to use C-style strings, you know the original length of the string, and you know the adjustments you will be making.  Thus repeatedly calling `strlen()` is not necessary -- you *know* the length of the string before you adjusted it, and you know the adjustments you will be making, thus you know the "new" string length after the adjustments.  As long as you stick the null in the proper place, there is no need for repeated calls to strlen().

Comment: @ArminMontigny if Array char has fixed size 15 why can hold string after modified?

Comment: @Pegasus because your code has *undefined behavior*, leading to a **buffer overflow** writing into surrounding memory.  The array is just a chunk of memory, the compiler doesn't enforce you stay in the bounds of the array, that is your job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `<cstring>` and `<string.h>` are the same thing, just that `<cstring>` wraps the contents of `<string.h>` into the `std` namespace.  There is no need to use both headers, use one or the other - use `<string.h>` in C, and `<cstring>` in C++.

More importantly, `x` is a fixed-sized array of 16 `char`s, as it is being initialized with a string literal containing 15 alpha-numerics + a null terminator.  This is the same as if you had done the following instead:

```cpp
//char x[] = "abcdefghi123456";
char x[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','1','2','3','4','5','6','\0'};
```

Thus, the initial `strlen(x)` returns 15 (because the null terminator is not counted).  `15 % 4` is not 0, so the `while` loop is entered, and on its very 1st iteration, `x+strlen(x)` points to the array's `'\0'` null terminator:

```
{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','1','2','3','4','5','6','\0'}
  ^                                                           ^
  |                                                           |
  x                                                         x + 15
```

Which `memcpy()` then overwrites with `'n'`:

```cpp
{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','1','2','3','4','5','6','n'};
                                                              ^
```

From that point on, `x` is no longer null-terminated, so any further uses of `strlen(x)` will cause **undefined behavior** due to it reaching beyond the bounds of the array into surrounding memory.

For what you are trying to do, use `std::string` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main () {
    
    string x = "abcdefghi123456";  // length 15
    
    cout << "original string length: " << x.size() << endl;
    cout << "string before modified: " << x << endl;
    
    while ((x.size() % 4) != 0)
    {
        x += 'n';
    }
        
    /* alternatively:
    x.resize((x.size() + 3) & ~3, 'n');
    */

    cout << "string length after modified: " << x.size() << endl;
    cout << "string after modified: " << x << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, problem solved